# Xcode WKWebView HTML Content Scrolling Even Though There Is No Content To Scroll

Tags: html, swift, xcode, scroll, wkwebview

In Xcode, I put a `WKWebView` in a view controller to display a `contenteditable <div>`. This is so that I could make a rich text editor. However, it doesn't seem to be scrolling properly. When the div is clicked on, a keyboard appears, and the web view is resized to fit it. However, when it is resized, the page becomes scrollable, even though there is no content below.

Here is the HTML being used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
html, body {
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content" contenteditable="true">
</div>
<script>
var content = document.getElementById("content")
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When the keyboard appears, the bottom constraint is moved.
Here is a gif of what is happening. Notice when the keyboard comes up, the webview suddenly has a scrollbar and supports scrolling, and I can scroll the blue box upward. Why? there is nothing there.
[image: Video of glitch]

How do I fix this?

**Edit:** Even weirder, after the keyboard goes down if you click on it again, it doesn't scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. If you add this line to the content div's css:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Then this line to when you are loading the web view:

```
webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

Then it will disable page scrolling, not including the content box.